# "First time at X place" or "first time in X place"?

Tags: word-choice

What's the correct construction? And why?

Example sentence:

> "This was my first time **at** Oxford University"
>
> "This was my first time **in** Oxford University"

Comment: How about "this was my first time **to** Oxford University"?

Comment: If you are only asking about these examples, why use "X" in your title? If you mean preposition usage with any place, your question is too broad. At best, more context would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This was my first time *at* Oxford University** makes more sense than ***in***. Or, as Andrew stated, ***to*** also works well.

***At*** and ***to*** both connote visiting Oxford University as an outsider -- perhaps as a tourist or an applicant or a guest lecturer.

***In*** connotes that I am a part of the institution and am a member of the community of Oxford University, such as an enrolled student, a professor, or staff member.

So if I became a member of Oxford University on separate occasions, for example as an undergraduate student and then years later as a professor, then, yes, I could say **This was my first time *in* Oxford University** when referring to my undergraduate experience. Otherwise, ***at*** makes more sense given the context of the sentence.

Comment: Regarding your assertion that ***in** connotes that I am a part of the institution...*, I believe it might not be true cross-dialect.

Comment: What dialect(s) are you speaking of?

Comment: British and American English.